# DirectWrite.TextLayout transform matrix has no effect

Tags: directx, direct2d, sharpdx, directwrite

I'm using DirectWrite (through [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/)) to draw a TextLayout and it works as expected except for a couple things. I'm calling this TextLayout constructor:

http://sharpdx.org/documentation/api/m-sharpdx-directwrite-textlayout--ctor-2

My code is pretty straight forward:

```
// define 45 deg rotation matrix
var transformMatrix = new SharpDX.DirectWrite.Matrix();
transformMatrix.M11 = 0.7f;
transformMatrix.M12 = 0.7f;
transformMatrix.M21 = -0.7f;
transformMatrix.M22 = 0.7f;
transformMatrix.Dx = 0;
transformMatrix.Dy = 0;

var pixelsPerDip = 5;

var TextLayout = new SharpDX.DirectWrite.TextLayout(DWFactory, "Hello world!",
        TextFormat, 400, 200, pixelsPerDip, transformMatrix, true);
```

I can change the transform matrix to any values whatsoever but it has no effect on my output. I've also found that `pixelsPerDip` has no effect except for not drawing the text when I specify zero. I dug into the SharpDX source and these inputs seem to be handled correctly. What am I doing wrong?

The TextLayout constructor I'm using calls `CreateGdiCompatibleTextLayout()`. Is it possible that something else I'm doing/using is not GDI compatible which then causes my issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transform passed to the IDWriteTextLayout constructor only affects hinting/grid-fitting and subtle metrics of layout (and unless you need GDI compatible pixel aligned metrics, the other constructor to create a natural layout will give more accurate subpixel layout). To *draw* a text layout with a different orientation, you have to set the transform of whatever you are using to draw onto (SetTransform if you are using the D2D device context/render target or SetCurrentTransform if IDWriteBitmapRenderTarget).